# Why is my GET Request getting hung up in Node using Fetch

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, node-fetch

`getDocuments` request never completes/stays pending. What am I missing?

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Grid from './Grid';
import apis from '../api/index';

export default function App(props) {

  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    async function initialize() {
      await apis.getDocuments().then(documents => {
        setDocuments(documents.data.data);
      });
    }

    initialize();
  }, []);
    
  return ( <Grid documents={documents} /> )
}
```

Controller.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.getDocuments = async (req, res) => {
  // added 'return' before fetch
  return fetch('EXTERNAL API ENDPOINT', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {"api-key": "API KEY"}
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
    return json
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

also tried this syntax:

```
//  added cors
exports.getDocuments = async () => {
  console.log("getting documents...");

  const response = await fetch(URL, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-api-key": "KEY"
    }
  })

  const result = await response.json();
  console.log('result', result);
  return result;

};
```

server index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const { getDocuments } = require('./controllers/Controller');

const router = require('./routes');

const app = express();

//  enable CORS for all origins to allow development with local server
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3002"}));

app.use('/api', router);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('This is the backend/API');
})

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4200);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

[image]

with server on localhost:
[image]

Comment: You don't actually do anything with the promise fetch returns. Your async function doesn't await anything, nor do you return then promise chain.

Comment: You need a `return` as in `return fetch(). then(...)`.  Thus your async `getDocuments()` function just returns a no-op promise that isn't connected at all to your `fetch()` call.

Comment: Updated to `return fetch('EXTERNAL API ENDPOINT', {` but still `getDocuments` is pending

Comment: Domain `testappsj01.org` does not exist. Are you sure you typed the correct url? Are there any errors in the console? Also using console.log in the `.catch` is not recommended, you are risking to miss some important issues. At least do `console.error`, it'll at least show you a red warning sign in the devtools, so you'll notice the issue.

Comment: `testappsj01.org` is my local dev server. No errors in the console, just getDocuments pending.

Comment: @dikuw in your screenshot no response was received. Check if that url works in the browser. Also check if you have CORS enabled, basically your server should return a header `access-control-allow-origin: *`. Keep in mind that you are sending a cross origin request from `http://localhost:3002` to the server `http://testappsj01.org`, so even if the issue is in CORS settings this header might not help at all, cuz in the last versions of Chrome they banned cross origin requests without HTTPS. In that case try to host your frontend at that same domain `testappsj01.org` or its subdomains.

Comment: I think I had cors handed in `index.js` (added above), but added it just in case. When I point my browser to `http://testappsj01.org:4200/` I do get "This is the backend/API"

Comment: I put the server on localhost:4200 but get the same result

Comment: Your custom header on the request will require CORs pre-flight support on the server (an OPTIONS request) if this is a cross origin request.

Comment: @jfriend00 that request is made server-side though. No CORS issues there

Comment: @Phil - The OP is showing multiple Chrome inspector screenshots which sure looks like client-side requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 to me it looks like the client-side app makes a request to Express (note the 4200 port) which makes a request to a different upstream service. OP has `cors()` configured in their Express app

Comment: What is `apis.getDocuments()`? `getDocuments` you have shown appears to be server code. And why are you importing `getDocuments` in `index.js` and then doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `getDocuments` is added to your `/api` router like this

```js
router.get("/getDocuments", getDocuments);
```

Express does not use the return value of route handlers. Instead, you need to send a response.

You need to change your controller to be like the following

```js
exports.getDocuments = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("getting documents...");

  const url = "EXTERNAL API ENDPOINT";
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "x-api-key": "KEY",
      },
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      // log details of unsuccessful responses
      console.error(
        "Fetch failed",
        url,
        response.status,
        await response.text(),
      );
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch from upstream");
    }

    //    
    res.json(await response.json()); // send a response
    //   

  } catch (err) {
    // propagate the error to Express' error handlers
    next(err);
  }
};
```

---

Note, the `try..catch` is not required if using Express v5+

Comment: Why do you attempt `await response.text()` when `!res.ok`?

Comment: @jfriend00 to get the response body. It could be an error message describing any issues (common with a 400 / 429 response status). At that stage, it's completely safe to use

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the return statement before your fetch call, otherwise you're not returning anything